# Play Framework(Scala) Compilation not working propery

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

```
val auth = for{....} yield {....}
val redirect : Result = Redirect(routes.PageController.landing())
auth.getOrElse{
  Future(redirect)
}
```

Error :

```
/home/orkun/Workspace/DatabaseProject/app/controllers/PageController.scala:104: 
type mismatch;
   found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Object]
   required:  scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
```

Compiler giving me this error. I don't know why I checked everyting. It was working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `auth` is not `Future[Result]`, it's `Future[T]`, where `T` doesn't share a parent class with `Result`. This makes `getOrElse` infer the common parent as `java.lang.Object`, making the return type incorrect.

You need to fix your `for-yield` statement.

Comment: I am sorry for delay and i finished my project thanks to you :). Otherwise i would struggle a lot.